# How is ioctl handled in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, ioctl

When I trigger ioctl. Does linux just call ioctl from some fops struct, or does it do something more (handle some basic operations). I think I heard this once, but there is little information about ioctl on the internet.

So, are all these operations handled by relevant modules, or are some of them handled by the kernel. If so, which ones? Those listed in /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h file?